# Combining two or more verbs for ありがとう

Tags: grammar

I have seen that to express a sequence of verbs, you can use the て-form,

> 食堂に行って、昼ご飯を食べて、昼寝をする。

and the same form is used when thanking with various formalities,

> 教えてくれてありがとう
>
> 教えていただいてありがとうございます
>
> 教えていただきありがとうございます

Then would it be correct to simply replace 教えて with some collection of て-form verbs, say,

> 添削して説明して...ありがとう

Or would that be too unnatural, and something like

> 色々ありがとう

is preferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the sentence:

> 「食堂{しょくどう}に行{い}って、昼{ひる}ご飯{はん}を食{た}べて、昼寝{ひるね}をする。」

is a completely natural-sounding one, it would not generally be a very natural-sounding sentence if one tried to employ multiple verbs in front of 「ありがとう」.  In this case, it is different from English where one can naturally say:

"Thank you for (verb 1)ing and (verb 2)ing for me yesterday!"

For one thing, 「ありがとう」 is a fixed phrase and grammatically speaking, it does not have a wide application.

「教{おし}えてくれてありがとう」 is fine as it is "simple" enough.

「添削{てんさく}して説明{せつめい}して...ありがとう」, however, is definitely not.  It sounds very... "foreign" for a lack of words.  It sounds "translated".  Native speakers would phrase it as:

> 「添削してくれて、**また**説明**まで**してくれて本当にありがとう。」

or slightly more formally:

> 「（ご）添削いただき、**かつ**（ご）説明**まで**していただき、まことにありがとうございました。」

**Point is we tend to use the connectors 「また」、「かつ」、「なおかつ」. etc.  We also tend to repeat 「くれて」、「いただき」、「いただいて」, etc. as well**.

Finally,

> 「色々{いろいろ}ありがとう」

is a totally different kind of sentence without using a verb, so it is difficult for me to say anything productive about it except that it is a valid phrase.

Answer (score 1):

You can use くれる when combining verbs with ありがとう。

> 一緒にご飯を食べた。
>   → 一緒にご飯を食べてくれてありがとう。

so, below makes sense;

> 添削して、説明してくれて、ありがとう。

or, simply just

> 添削と説明、ありがとう。(most preferred, I think)

Comment: Though the last option becomes unavailable when you have a non-*suru* verb like 助ける or 正す or くる or whatever instead of 説明.